# How do I get the font in an SVG to display in the web page?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

I have uploaded an SVG to my website, but the font is not displaying correctly. It is defaulting to Times.

I've tried importing Josefin Sans from fonts.google.com, and embedding the link in the  tag.

novagrappling.com/rules

Comment: You add the custom font in the SVG: [How do I use a custom font in an SVG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/how-do-i-use-a-custom-font-in-an-svg-image-on-my-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please embed your google font in your SVG using , here is the code which i have applied in your SVG, it's working perfectly.[image]

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
    text
    {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

    }
    tspan
    {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

    }
 </style>
</defs>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've checked my SVG code, and there are many different <defs> sections... around 70! does it matter where I embed the google font?

Comment: Please add After <svg> opening tag, so that, HTML capture it and apply on all elements defined in SVG.

Comment: it has changed the font for me, but not to Josefin Sans. *edit* it works great in Chrome, but not Safari

Comment: I have applied font, You can download from here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biue747rr0ddl3a/giweight.svg?dl=0)

Comment: I've compared and our code is identical, still doesn't work right in Safari for me for some reason

Comment: Which software you have used for creating this SVG?

Comment: It was a table created in Pages, exported as PDF, and edited in Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Please use, this SVG, i have created outline, now, no need for font, it's converted in objects [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwx5jnj3ezyp68t/Some.svg?dl=0)

Comment: For me to do the same, do I simply expand the text in illustrator?

Comment: While Exporting SVG, you just have to click on convert to outline, it will not export text instead it will give you path in SVG which means it will create an object, which will be further no need for font. You can view this option here in image linked:-[link](https://ibb.co/hgcYKrQ)